# If it possible in typescript to clone error with some modifications?

Tags: javascript, typescript, react-native, axios, sentry

I stucked with an issue - I'm trying to use Sentry.captureException with received error, but before that i'm trying to change error message. Spent a lot of time to find an answer to my question, but i had no success.
How could i create a new error with type Error | AxiosError and clone into that variable all the properties and change message? I can't use custom errors, because i don't want to change a lot of code.

Comment: Please show what you have tried and what issues you have with it including your expected results.

Comment: `const err = new Error('a'); err.message = 'b'; console.log(err.toString())` What was the problem?

Comment: Thank you guys, I'm sorry, you gave me a chance to think a little bit more, and i'll fix this with a custom message and additional data inside the Sentry Scope.

Answer (score 1):

```
  await axios.get("xxx").then(result => {
    // Success
  }).catch((err: AxiosError) => {
    Sentry.captureException({
      ...err,
      response: {
        ...err.response,
        data: "Custom error message"
      }
    });
  });
```

Does this approach solve the problem?

Comment: Thanks! tried this approach, but as a result - Sentry can't identify this object as error from which it could take a title and description for it's admin panel. But now i understand that all that i need - only to create error with my custom message and all other information i can send from scope.